# when I run ionic app on windows it shows Error: Cannot find module "@angular/compiler"

Tags: ionic-framework

```
[app-scripts] (node:2056) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: A watch configured to watch the following paths failed to start. It likely that a file referenced does not exist: F:\ionic\myfolder\src\assets\**\*, F:\ionic\myfolder\src\index.html, F:\ionic\myfolder\src\manifest.json, F:\ionic\myfolder\src\service-worker.js, F:\ionic\myfolder\node_modules\ionicons\dist\fonts\**\*, F:\ionic\myfolder\node_modules\ionic-angular\fonts\**\*, F:\ionic\myfolder\node_modules\ionic-angular\polyfills\polyfills.js, F:\ionic\myfolder\node_modules\sw-toolbox\sw-toolbox.js
```

Comment: Followings are my environment
ionic -v 5.4.16
ionic version 5.4.16
node -v  v14.4.0
OS: windows 10

Comment: and Android Studio3.3

Answer (score 0):

I think Angular CLI is not install. Try to install Angular CLI first. Run below command in command prompt-

```
npm install -g @angular/cli
```

I hope it will solve the problem :)

Comment: Can you create a sample application and try to run it. Then check if the problem exists.

Answer (score 0):

First delete your current angular/cli. then run comand `npm i --save-dev @angular/compiler-cli` and perform below steps.

1. Delete your node_modules folder
2. `npm cache clean --force`
3. `npm install`